# Algorithm writing in latex

Tags: amsmath, algorithms

How can I write this algorithm in left align latex of 2 column?

[image]

I have tried this but its not working

```
    \textit{repeat till convergence}
\begin{equation}\small
\label{eq_04}
{
W_{i+1} = W_i - \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial W_i}f(W_i)
}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

(Remark: I updated this answer completely after the OP provided more information about formatting requirements.)

The following solution works by setting up a dedicated environment called `myalgo`. The "outer" `equation` environment assures that there's some vertical separation between the algo material and the text above and below it, and it also provides an equation number. The "inner" `minipage` environment, whose width is set to `0.9\columnwidth`, assures that each line starts flush-left within the `minipage`. Instances of `myalg` may be cross-referenced via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newenvironment{myalgo}{%
   \begin{equation}\begin{minipage}{0.9\columnwidth}\obeylines}{%
   \end{minipage}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Generally, for a simple supervised learning the \dots
\begin{myalgo} \label{alg:1}
\qquad\textit{repeat until convergence}
\{
$\displaystyle W_{i+1} = W_i - \alpha \frac{\partial}{\partial W_i} f(W_i)$
\}
\end{myalgo}
Here $W_i$ are network parameters of each \dots

A cross-reference to algorithm \ref{alg:1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. its coming in the middle. However, i want it to be left align in two column article. Also, the equation number is number coming with this

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA - Please edit your posting to state all of your formatting requirements up front. How was I supposed to know that you use a two-column layout?

Comment: please do accept my apology, i have updated my question